# Template not updating when elements in array change

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have an interesting setup in my template that uses values in an array to calculate and display a number

```
{{moduleProps.totals | values | sum | currency:'USD':true:'1.0-0'}}
```

Here is the values pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { values } from 'lodash';

@Pipe({
  name: 'values',
})
export class ValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, ...args) {
    if(value){
      return values(value);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the sum pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { reduce } from 'lodash';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sum',
})
export class SumPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, ...args) {
    if(value){
      return reduce(value,(a,b)=>a+b,0);
    }
  }
}
```

The array I'm using for this looks something like this...

```
[donation_earnings: 868, donation_pledges: 10, raffle_purchase_earnings: 4, fixed_purchase_earnings: 6, bid_earnings: 38]
```

When I try to go update one of these numbers later on like this...

this.moduleProps.totals.donation_pledges += events[0].amount;

Where the `events[0].amount` should be a number added to whatever the current number of that object property is.

When I do this, however, the template is not updating. When I log out the object property after doing the math I see the number is changed but the template doesn't hear about it.

After I do this I am also calling

this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

To help with change detection on another array of items being pushed and popped but this doesn't seem to also be picking up the changes to the values in the array.

I have also tried running this in a `NgZone.run()` but that wasn't updating the template either.

Is there some sort of caveat I don't understand yet about the way angular 2 handles array change detection?

**EDIT:**

Also when I output the individual object properties to the page I see their numbers changing, it's only the number that's passed through the pipes that isn't updating

Comment: If you are changing the data inside the pipe you need to tell angular that that pipe is impure  by adding ```pure:false``` in the decorator.